# For all Infinity Stones to be used, did it have to be a snap? Or was that Thanos' choice?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, infinity-stones

We all know Thanos specifically chose to snap to use all the Infinity Stones to wipe out half the universe. Even everyone else who gets an Infinity Gauntlet seems to have to snap in order to use all the Stones.

Did it *have* to be a snap in order to use all the Infinity Stones? Why wasn't it a clap? Or something else? I get Thanos *chose* to do a snap but if he had chosen to do a clap or something else, would it have worked?

The reason I'm not entirely sure is because Tony builds a gauntlet as well and he's not working off Thanos' gauntlet but he comes to the same conclusion-snap to use all Infinity Stones, granted this may have been easiest, but I'm still curious if it *needed* to be a snap or all gauntlets were just designed that way.

I'm specifically asking for lore on using all 6 stones. I know there's duplicates out there about how specifically the gauntlet is activated, but I'm asking if, in order to use all 6 infinity stones, a snap, by *any* party, whether it be Thanos, Hulk, Tony, other celestials, etc, is required on *any* gauntlet (or any device using all 6 stones), or if that was simply a choice by all parties that have used all 6 stones thus far.

Comment: Yes, has been [asked before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212668/why-does-snapping-your-fingers-activate-the-infinity-gauntlet)

Comment: Let me be clear, I'm not asking why both closing your first and snapping work, I'm asking why both Thanos and Hulk and Tony have to snap *at all* instead of some other gesture. Would *any* gesture use up all 6 stones (if the gauntlet was designed for a clap)? Or does it have to be a snap specifically to use the stones? If so are the gauntlets designed to be snapped or is it innate?

Comment: Hulk and Tony almost certainly did it because that's what Thanos did and Gamora seems to think it is somewhat required _"If he gets all six Infinity Stones, he can do it with the snap of his fingers, like this."_. This is all stated on the duplicate though of course.

Comment: Yeah but the *could* is the important part there. It seems to me that he doesn't *have* to snap, it's just what he's chosen to do in order to use all infinity stones on that specific gauntlet. But, even if Hulk and Tony did it because Thanos did it, does that mean a snap *isn't* required? This stuff the duplicate doesn't really answer. The duplicate simply says the director's choice for the snap and what both snapping and closing his fist does as well as some quotes for the snap. Basically I'm looking for lore on using 6 infinity stones and that duplicate doesn't seem to provide it.

Comment: Again the duplicate answers this and it boils down to "we don't know if it really is required but all evidence suggests that is has to be a snap because that is what characters say and what they do".

Comment: The first answer is writers decision on why he closes his fist in the movie as well as why *the writers* chose a snap in the movie (they could've changed it). The second answer is just wrong as we see he does need to close his fist to use at least one stone. All answers and comments have nothing to do with if he needs to snap in order to use all 6 stones, of if he could've asked the dwarves to make him a gauntlet that activates all stones when he claps or something. But if it really boils down to "we don't know" and all evidence doesn't confirm it, then I guess nevermind lol.